# Wordpress Subdirectory giving 404

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to **copy** the root WP installation to a sub directory.
(I changed the permalinks in the new copy database to the subdirectory links)

The subdirectory will be root/b2b/

When I try to reach the subdirectory I get redirected to a 404 page.

This is the .htaccess in the root

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

In the subdirectory I currently have no .htaccess since everything that I tried is not working.

I checked the other topics but none of them seems to work for me.

Answer (score 6):

Replace following line

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule . /b2b/index.php [L]
```

and

```
RewriteBase /
```

to

```
RewriteBase /b2b/
```

Comment: Could you please specify if I should to this in the root .htacces or copy the root .htacces to the sub and edit these lines there?

Comment: you can do it in root htaccess

Comment: have you changed url in wp_options?

Comment: are you using multisite?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the RewriteBase

```
RewriteBase b2b
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the root of your site.

index.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./b2b/wp-blog-header.php');
```

Has the added benefit of not needing to mess with the .htaccess if you're uncomfortable with that.

Comment: Thanks, this is the original index.php in the ROOT installation:


/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
Should I add this on the last line on the root index.php or in the sub index? :require('./b2b/wp-blog-header.php');

Comment: Put it in the root of your site - it will then include the correct WordPress header. **Take note** that the require line at the end includes your subdirectory. Afterwards, make sure that you go into wp-admin and update the Settings > General page so that it knows about the move.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't seems to work. I copied the code to my index.php in my ROOT wp installation. But still no succes, the subdomain is still returning a 404

Comment: Sorry, what subdomain? If you're still getting no joy then updating the root .htaccess should have the same effect.

Comment: Sorry John I mean subdirectory, that's what I am encountering too with the .htacces modifications. I can't seem to figure it out why it's not working. 

On other installations it normally works with some .htacces modifications but now it won't